# Java - how to tell class of an object?

Tags: java, oop, programming-languages

Given a method that accepts as a parameter a certain supertype.  Is there any way, within that method, to determine the actual class of the object that was passed to it? I.e. if a subtype of the allowable parameter was actually passed, is there a way to find out which type it is?  If this isn't possible can someone explain why not (from a language design perspective)?  Thanks

Update:  just to make sure I was clear

```
Context: MySubType extends MyType

void doSomething(MyType myType) {
  //determine if myType is MyType OR one of its subclasses
  //i.e. if MySubType is passed as a parameter, I know that it can be explicitly
  //cast to a MySubType, but how can I ascertain that its this type
  //considering that there could be many subclasses of MyType
}
```

Since the method signature specifies the parameter as being `MyType`, then how can one tell if the object is actually a subtype of `MyType` (and which one).

Comment: You do not want to do this.  Instead, you want all subclasses of the "certain supertype" to have common methods and attributes so they are polymorphic.  Why are you avoiding a polymorphic solution?

Comment: I'm not avoiding a polymorphic solution, I'm just wondering if its possible.  And if its not possible (without reflection perhaps as someone suggested), why not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the javadoc for the Object class, you will find that every object supports `getClass()`. That's the `Class` of the object, and you can go from there.

If the object is `MyType` then `getClass() == MyType.class'. If the object is a superclass, then`getClass() != MyType.class`.

There are only these possibilities. If the type of the param is `MyType`, and `MyType` is a class and not an interface, then either the object is `MyClass` or it's a subtype. If it's a subtype, then `getClass()` is returning the `Class` for the subtype. You can use the API of `Class` to explore it.

You can, of course, use reflection to explore the type hierarchy. You can ask `MyType.class` for a list of its direct subclasses, and recurse from there, and have a fine old time. But you don't need to.

Comment: what if the object is a subclass?  then getClass() == MyType.class, BUT how can I find out that getClass()==MySubType.class?

Comment: bmargulies's answer is right, that allows you know if the object is of type MyType; if it's not, then it must be one subclass - it's difficult to understand what more do you need.

Comment: Ok - if its not MyType then it must be a subclass - I agree with that.  I am wondering how to figure out WHICH subclass it is?  All the other answers so far suggest using instanceof (or something similar).  But I am wondering why you have to explicitly test for this.  Why can't there be an operation that tells you that MyType is this or that subclass?  Hopefully I'm clear..this is just kind of hard to articulate.

Comment: The result of getClass() *is* the subclass. Its a Class object that represents the class.

Comment: But getClass() tells you that: WHICH subclass it is. It tells you that at runtime, granted. It seem that you are thinking in something like taking into acount in your code "all the possible subclasses", specifically and individually - but you obviously cannot "know" all the possible subclasses at compile time, anyone can create its own subclass class and call your method with an instance of that class.

Comment: thanks leonbloy, what you said makes sense.  i got really mixed up for a while.  I think I have it straight now thanks to your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is -- there's a built in reflection API called Trail that allows you to examine the types of any instance of a class. The method `getClass()` that is inherited from the `Object` class will give you a `Class` object that you can examine. A good starting point is the [Trail tutorial from Sun](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/reflect/class/classNew.html).

Comment: Pretty sure that Trail is just Sun's old name for tutorials.  This is generally known as the reflection API :-p

Comment: Well that's thoroughly embarrassing (:

Answer (score 1):

I assume that MyType is the superclass type, right?

1/ If you just want to know that it does not belong to your super class type:
you can check

```
if (m.getClass() != MyType.getClass())
```

2/ If you want to check if m belongs to a certain subclass, I don't think there is a way, you have to hard code it like

```
if (m.getClass() == MySubType) {
}
```

or you can use:

```
if (!(m instanceof MySubType)) {
}
```

Comment: Exactly, this is what I assumed.  But I am wondering why this is?  I konw that the type passed to the method can be determined at runtime, but why isn't there an easy common way to do this (without reflection)? Is there usually no need for this feature?

Comment: yeah, because usally, when you pass as a supertype, you want polymorphism, which means that you want to treat all of the parameter object as the same one. So, it will not be good in terms of OOP if you have to treat every subtype differently, which make polymorphism useless. 
I don't know what you need to do, but I think that you can create another interface type to abstract all of the subclass type you need to if else

Comment: i think instanceof is just what you need.

if (object instanceof MyType)

 means: is this object instance of MyType or any of MyType's subclasses